# sudo: Undefined variable error at any command

Tags: ssh, web-applications, root, sudo

I am trying to install openproject with sudo. 
But if I am entering any sudo command I get the following error: 
`sudo: Undefined variable.`

Like: 
If I want to switch in root with:

```
$sudo su
```

I am getting this error.

Thanks in advance
Conga

Comment: What output of the command `which sudo` you get?

Comment: I am getting "wich: command not found". :(

Comment: Okay, other bash commands,  say `ls` and `cd` work fine?

Comment: Firstly, I am so thankful for you help! Yes, ls and cd is working fine.

Comment: Well, it looks like you don't have sudo install. What is your environment? Are you able to install it? If not, consider using `su` instead.

Comment: Thank you a lot, worked now! :)